# Ruby Fixnum comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixnum

After gathering data from a web service, I'm trying to pull out only those records that have a value for a particular field > 0. The field that I'm checking is a FixNum field. I have tried multiple things like .nil? or > 0 etc. But none of them seem to work.

Here is how the code goes:

```
 results.each do |r|
    # puts "came"
     if r['efforRemaining'] % 1 != 0 #i tried r['efforRemaining'].nil? ..
    # i have values like 0.4, 0.5 etc for the field, hence i need to check if the value is greater than 0 or not only
       puts "came!"
      puts "#{r['mstone']} ... #{r['assignee']['id']} ... #{r['effortRemaining'].to_f}"
     end
  end
```

Could somebody let me know how to do this?
thanks,

Comment: If `r['efforRemaining']` is a `Fixnum`, `r['efforRemaining'] % 1` will *always* be `0`.

Comment: Is the value definitely stored as a Fixnum (ie not a String)? What do you get when you `puts r['effortRemaining'].inspect`

Comment: @AndyH,
I get either 'nil' or the value (4 or ".01")

Comment: If this is your actual code, there's a typo that could explain your problem: 'efforRemaining' should be 'effortRemaining', no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `puts r['effortRemaining'].inspect` comes out in quote marks, that means it is a string and you need to convert it to a number before you compare it.

This should work:

```
if r['effortRemaining'].to_f > 0
```

Comment: that throws an error: undefined method `>' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
However, I found a workaround :

if !r['effortRemaining'].to_s.empty?

This works fine!

Comment: Under what circumstances does `to_f` return false?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The `NoMethodError` you describe occurs because you are doing something like `false > 0`, and that would happen if `r['effortRemaining'].to_f` returned false. Except I don't understand how that would happen, `to_f` should always return a number... `nil.to_f`, `"not a number".to_f` both return 0.0, not false.